# Not work Facebook comment plugin in tabs (white block)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

Use Facebook comment plugin in tabs. When load page first time, Facebook comment plugin work good, but when click other tabs and back on Facebook tab, Facebook comment plugin disappeare and instead it has a white block. If you reload the page, Facebook comment plugin newly displayed. Any one had the same problem before?

Example page: http://socext.com/demo/soccomments/76-kak-sbrosit-parol-administratora-joomla.html

Answer (score 1):

The issue is easy to fix with some JavaScript. When the user click on the Facebook button, call `FB.XFBML.parse();` in your code (i.e. in the onclick method or when the page is first loaded) and the comments plugin will display correctly everything.

If that doesn't work, use jQuery UI and bind to the tabs so that `FB.XFBML.parse();` when the tabs are clicked.

Comment: I had a similar problem and this fixed it. Thanks!